# Test a property value using a matcher

Tags: scala, scalatest, matcher

One can use [have](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingArbitraryProperties) to check if property equals to a value.

Is there some way to check the property not for equality, but to check if it satisfies a matcher?

Following compiles, but unsurprisingly it does not work, as the property is tested for equality with the matcher value.

```
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

class MainTest extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers {
  case class Book(title: String, author: List[String], pubYear: Int)
  "Something" should "work" in {
    val book = Book("Programming in Scala", List("Odersky", "Spoon", "Venners"), 2008)
    book should have (
      Symbol("title") ("Programming in Scala"),
      Symbol("pubYear") (be >= 2006 and be <= 2010)
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [`Inside`](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/main/jvm/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/Inside.scala) which allows you to assert statements about case class properties using pattern matching:

```
  "Something" should "work" in {
    inside (book) { case Book(title, _, pubYear) =>
      title should be ("Programming in Scala")
      pubYear should (be >= 2008 and be <= 2010)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You re looking for `matchPattern`:

```
book should matchPattern { 
 case Book("Programming in Scala", _, year) if 2006 to 2010 contains year =>
}
```